mongodb add a derived field on array of object
I have the following data and I want to add 2 fields where one of them is derived from one of the existing field:
[
  {
    profiles: [
      {
        name: "test 1",
        value: 123
      },
      {
        name: "test 2",
        value: 234
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    profiles: [
      {
        name: "test 3",
        value: 345
      },
      {
        name: "test 4",
        value: 456
      }
    ]
  }
]

I tried the following but it does not copy the value properly:
db.collection.update({
  "profiles.adjustedValue": null
},
{
  $set: {
    "profiles.$[].adjustedValue": "profiles.$[].value",
    "profiles.$[].adjustmentReason": "n/a"
  }
},
{
  multi: true
})


you will need to use aggregation with update and probably do a $map

meant something like https://mongoplayground.net/p/l4WoZfHgj24 but change according to ur needs

Thanks cmgchess; for reference this was the provided solution:
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      profiles: {
        $map: {
          input: "$profiles",
          as: "profile",
          in: {
            name: "$$profile.name",
            value: "$$profile.value",
            adjustedValue: {
              $cond: {
                if: {
                  $ifNull: [
                    "$$profile.adjustedValue",
                    false
                  ]
                },
                then: "$$profile.adjustedValue",
                else: "$$profile.value"
              }
            },
            adjustmentReason: {
              $cond: {
                if: {
                  $ifNull: [
                    "$$profile.adjustedValue",
                    false
                  ]
                },
                then: "$$profile.adjustmentReason",
                else: "n/a"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  multi: true
})

https://mongoplayground.net/p/GfbPNQTpcOl

Here is a slightly shorter version.
